# XPath query to select all href attributes of <a> tag, which 'class' attribute equals specified string

Tags: xpath

I don't know why following query doesn't work:

```
//a/@href[@class='specified_string']
```

Comment: As the class attribute may contain multiple class names separated by spaces, you probably actually want: `//a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '), 'some_class_name')]/@href`

Comment: @singpolyma: Good point. Just a nitpick: it is `' some_class_name '` (with spaces around), *not* `'some_class_name'`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try it the other way round:

```
//a[@class='specified_string']/@href
```

After all, `class` is an attribute of the `<a>` element, not an attribute of the `href` attribute.

Comment: Yes I think it works, but the problem is that query returns attributes, and I want to retrieve attributes' values. I'm writing it in Java and it returned me NodeList of length 2. When I try to print it out, it just prints two xml headers:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
two and there is only two links that query will match, so it seems working. But I want to get values of this hrefs. How to do that?

Comment: That `NodeList` should contain the list of `Node`s representing the `href` attributes. So just running `getNodeValue()` on those nodes should give you the `href` attributes' values.

Comment: This is not working in my case, although I think it's totally right. My Chrome can use `//a[@name=  "topic"]` to extract the right a elements. But `//a[@name= "topic"]/@href` returns a list of [, , , , , ] as if there isn't a href attribute. This is the an "a element" as example: <a href="/topic/19778287" name="topic">XXX</a>

Comment: Just to let you guys know that that Xpath **actually worked**. But Chrome console somehow displays an empty-like list. When I assign that list to a variable and print that variable, everything I want is there. I am leaving my original comment there so other people with same issue can relate.

Answer (score 7):

**An attribute cannot have attributes. Only elements can have attributes.**

The original XPath expression:

```
//a/@href[@class='specified_string']
```

selects any `href` attribute of any `a` element, **such that the `href` attribute has an attribute `class`** whose value is `'specified_string'`.

**What you want is**:

```
//a[@class='specified_string']/@href
```

**that is: the `href` attribute of any `a` element that has `class` atribute with value `'specified_string'`.**

Answer (score 2):

You basically say that you are looking for an attribute named `href`, whose attribute (this is the error) `class` should be equal to `specified_string`.

But you need to find the attribute `href` of an element `a`, whose attribute `class` is `specified_string`.

(ndim's answer overlapped mine)

Answer (score 1):

There is not class attribute present in anchor tag I have href only. It is identified using `//*[@href='value']` but `//*a[@href='value']` is not working