# In R XML Xpath, @href is returning the text "href"

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am trying to get the contents of `href` using Xpath code as described in these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455349/xpath-query-get-attribute-href-from-a-tag) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691744/xpath-query-to-select-all-href-attributes-of-a-tag-which-class-attribute-eq). Unfortunately the code is returning the actual text "href" and several spaces in addition to the URL. How can I avoid that?

```
library(XML)

html <- readLines("http://www.msu.edu")
html.parse <- htmlParse(html)
Node <- getNodeSet(html.parse, "//div[@id='MSU-top-utilities']//a/@href")
Node[[1]]

# > Node[[1]]
#                  href 
# "students/index.html" 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLAttributeValue"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a named character vector. You can do:

```
as.character(Node[[1]])
```

which will give you

```
## [1] "students/index.html"
```

Alternately, here's a much better idiom in the `xml2` package:

```
library(xml2)

doc <- read_html("http://www.msu.edu")
nodes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//div[@id='MSU-top-utilities']//a")
xml_attr(nodes, "href")

## [1] "students/index.html"      "faculty-staff/index.html" "alumni/index.html"       
## [4] "businesses/index.html"    "visitors/index.html"
```